# Join Table on one record but calculate field based on other rows in the join

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to write a query to Identify my subscribers who have abandoned a shopping cart in the last day but also I need a calculated field that represents weather or not they have received and incentive in the last 7 days.

I have the following tables

AbandonCart_Subscribers
Sendlog

The first part of the query is easy, get abandoners in the last day

```
select a.* from AbandonCart_Subscribers 
where DATEDIFF(day,a.DateAbandoned,GETDATE()) <= 1
```

Here is my attempt to calculate the incentive but I am fairly certain it is not correct as IncentiveRecieved is always 0 even when I know it should not be...

```
select a.*, 
CASE 
  WHEN DATEDIFF(D,s.SENDDATE,GETDATE()) >= 7 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END As IncentiveRecieved
from AbandonCart_Subscribers a 
left join SendLog s on a.EmailAddress = s.EmailAddress and s.CampaignID IS NULL  
where
DATEDIFF(day,a.DateAbandoned,GETDATE()) <= 1
```

Here is a SQL fiddle with the objects and some data. I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f481f/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kishore is right in saying the main problem is that it should be <=7, not >=7. However, there is another problem.

As it stands, you could get multiple results. You don't want to do a left join on SendLog in case the same email address is in there more than once. Instead you should be getting a unique result from that table. There's a couple of ways of doing that; here is one such way which uses a derived table. The table I have called s will give you a unique list of emails that have been sent an incentive in the last week.

```
select a.*, 
CASE 
  WHEN s.EmailAddress is not null
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END As IncentiveRecieved
from AbandonCart_Subscribers a 
left join (select distinct EmailAddress
           from SendLog s 
           where s.CampaignID IS NULL
           and DATEDIFF(D,s.SENDDATE,GETDATE()) <= 7 
          ) s on a.EmailAddress = s.EmailAddress 
where DATEDIFF(day,a.DateAbandoned,GETDATE()) <= 1
```

Comment: I did finally figure this out an my solution is almost exactly what you provided. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable using a condition:

```
select a.*,(DATEDIFF(D,s.SENDDATE,GETDATE()) >= 7) as `IncentiveRecieved `
    from AbandonCart_Subscribers a 
    left join SendLog s on a.EmailAddress = s.EmailAddress and s.CampaignID IS NULL  
    where
    DATEDIFF(day,a.DateAbandoned,GETDATE()) <= 1
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

should it not be less than 7 instead of greater than 7?

select a.*,
CASE 
  WHEN DATEDIFF(D,s.SENDDATE,GETDATE()) <= 7  AND CampaignID is not null
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END As IncentiveRecieved
from AbandonCart_Subscribers a 
left join SendLog s on a.EmailAddress = s.EmailAddress --and s.CampaignID IS NULL
where
DATEDIFF(day,a.DateAbandoned,GETDATE()) <= 1

Hope this satisfies your need.

Comment: Yes, I have figured out the query and you are correct. It should have been greater than.